# Apostrophe issue in JavaScript with Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, fancybox-2

It's simple!

This is my dynamic `JavaScript` code with `Razor` markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.fancybox.open(
    [
        @foreach (var class in GenericClass)
        {
            var aux = "{ href: 'http://localhost:63095" + Url.RouteUrl("Image") + "' }";
            <Text>@aux</text>
            break;
        }
    ],
    { helpers: { thumbs: { width: 75, height: 50 } }
  });    
</script>
```

This is what I get in any web browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.fancybox.open(
    [
        { href: &#39;http://localhost:63095/Home/Image&#39; }
    ],
    { helpers: { thumbs: { width: 75, height: 50 } }
  });    
</script>
```

But this is what I really wanted to be generated:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.fancybox.open(
    [
        { href: 'http://localhost:63095/Home/Image' }
    ],
    { helpers: { thumbs: { width: 75, height: 50 } }
  });    
</script>
```

The problem is clear: instead of an **`apostrophe (')`** the output has **`&#39;`**. Does someone know how I can generate the **`'`** instead of **`&#39;`** ?

**OBSERVATION**: I already tried to do escaping and encoding but neither seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try including the value inline instead:

```
@foreach (var class in GenericClass)
{
  <Text>{ href: 'http://localhost:63095@(Url.RouteUrl("Image"))' }</text>
  break;
}
```

I believe that should fix the issue

---

**Raw Html Approach**

If you do need raw html you can use the following:

```
@Html.Raw(myString)
```

Just be very careful with this especially if you are including values entered by the user since it could cause XSS or other security issues.

Comment: @ViniciusB.Bizarri Oops, that was a copy paste error! Thanks!